# TypeError when using format string

Tags: python

Note: I searched for an answer on this site, but none of them helped me.

```
**TypeError: not enough arguments for format string**
```

So hi, and this is my first hour learning python. I decided to try out what I know already and wrote a code, but an error occurs with this line:

```
print("'%s' hired '%s' as troop in his first slot." % name, slot1)
```

Comment: I don't think you were searching in the right way.  Simply putting the error message into [google](https://www.google.ca/#q=typeerror+not+enough+arguments+for+format+string) gives many SO answers, and each of the first three explains the problem.

Comment: keep your question shorter. It was better before you dumped all of the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to provide a tuple argument to the string, otherwise it's only going to take the first thing.  when you have:

```
'%s %s' % a, b
```

it's parsed similarly (but not exaclty) like

```
('%s %s' % a), b
```

meaning the b isn't part of the argument to the `%` operator.  To fix this, parenthesize `a` and `b` to give a single tuple argument instead

```
'%s %s' % (a, b)
```

In your specific case

```
"'%s' hired '%s' as troop in his first slot." % (name, slot1)
```

Though you may want to consider the newer python `format` syntax

```
"'{}' hired '{}' as troop in his first slot.".format(name, slot1)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `print` statement must be

```
print("'%s' hired '%s' as troop in his first slot." % (name, slot1))
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused, so on that line I did need to use like this: 
print("'%s' hired '%s' as troop in his first slot." % (name, slot1))
But on other lines I used the code like this, and no error came:
print("Slots left: %s" % slotamount)

What is the difference, when to use which?

Comment: @LeDirt When you have a single variable, you don't need to use tuple, whenever there are multiple, you need to put them in a tuple.